# magento 2 - how to add more parameter to URL view product detail

Tags: magento2, product-view

How to add more parameter to URL view product detail.
I need add one more parameter in url of view product detail.
Anyone can help me?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add parameter directly after url.

```
<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl().'?param1=value1&param2=value2' ?>

//Get value using,
echo $this->getRequest()->getParam('param1');
```

Answer (score 0):

I got it working by using the parameter '_query'. See an example below:

```
$link = $configurableProduct->getUrlInStore([
    '_ignore_category' => false,
    '_query' => ['attrColourId' => 'xxx'],
    ]]);
```

I hope it helps.

Cheers,